# Ruby on Rails - conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapping, super

I have the following method

```
def providers
  if super.present?
    super.map(&:name).join("#{I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.shared.provider_name_separator')}<br>").html_safe
  else
    I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.data.no_data')
  end
end
```

The provider has the following model schema

```
"providers": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "relationship": ""
    }
  ],
```

The problem is, when the provider has a blank "name" and has a "relationship", it displays "nothing" - just a blank. I still want it to display a "--"(I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.data.no_data')).

I tried doing this,

```
def providers
  names = super.map(&:name).join("#{I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.shared.provider_name_separator')}<br>")
  names.present? ? names.html_safe : I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.data.no_data')
end
```

Still no luck. What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone show me some direction with this? Thank you in advance

To avoid confusion,
I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.shared.provider_name_separator') = ","
I18n.t('healtherecord_engine.data.no_data') = "--"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if super.present?
```

to

```
if super && super.any?(&:name)
```

Also note that calling super multiple times might be dangerous:

```
prov_hash = super
if prov_hash && prov_hash.any?(&:name)
```

Quite likely it can be further optimized, but this depends on the super method.

Comment: Well, the problem I found with this is, when there is `providers` array with one that has name and one with no name, the result is something like `name,`. But I just want the `name` here without comma.  @BroiSatse

Comment: In that case: `super.map(&:name).select(&:present?).join(...)`